# Webview throws error when press power button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application view I have web view. Now if the webview is loading the data and user press power button of the iphone to lock the device then some time the app halts. When user unlock the device then app throws this error message.

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:)
 failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

so will you please tell me how this problem can be solved. This problem happens often.

Answer (score 0):

check if the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` is fired (which it does when the user locks the iphone) then just stop  loading the webview...

```
[webView stopLoading];
```

let me know if this works...

Comment: try removing the previous application from the device first and the re-install it. don't forget to clean the project before compiling.

Comment: yes i try this too. I am stuck in this problem from last two days.